# Color map to show differences between grey level images

Tags: image, matlab, colors

I have two grey level images and I am looking for a "proper" way to show the difference image.

The difference image should be a color image and it should show negative, zero and positive values.

Currently I am using a color map that shows negative values as blue, positive value as yellow and zero value as grey (see for example "A color map to show differences between images" http://www.cb.uu.se/~cris/blog/index.php/archives/56).

The minimum value found in the difference image is mapped to RGB=(0, 0, 1) and the maximum value found in the difference image is mapped to RGB=(0.9, 0.9, 0), the mapping is linear.

Is there any reference in the literature (academic papers, books...) to such a map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reference, see the [(archived) page that helped push these colormaps](http://web.archive.org/web/20060329072947/http://www.research.ibm.com/people/l/lloydt/color/color.HTM); references are at the bottom of the page.

If you want to build such a colormap, i.e. one that is linear in saturation (as opposed to e.g. hue), you need [HSL2RGB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20292) from the File Exchange, and then you can construct a colormap like this:

```
cLength = 64; %# length of colormap
hue = [ones(floor(cLength/2),1)*0.66; ones(ceil(cLength/2),1)*0.16];
sat = [linspace(1,0,floor(cLength/2))';linspace(0,1,ceil(cLength/2))'];
lum = ones(cLength,1)*0.50;

cmap = hsl2rgb([hue,sat,lum]);

%# apply colormap
colormap(cmap)
```

For your visualization, if the most negative and the most positive difference are not the same, use [CAXIS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/caxis.html) to ensure that the color grey maps exactly to zero.

```
maxAbsDiff = max(abs(differenceImage(:)));
caxis([-maxAbsDiff,maxAbsDiff])
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the help for the [colormap function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/colormap.html).

You should a function to create the required color map (see `hot.m` as an example). For example:

```
function c = blueyellow(m)
if nargin < 1, m = size(get(gcf,'colormap'),1); end
x = (0:m-1)'/max(m-1,1);
c = bsxfun(@plus, [0 0 1], x * [0.9 0.9 -1]);
```

then run

```
colormap('blueyellow')
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not completely sure that this is exactly the same as the on described by Cris Luengo, because it doesn't include [0.4 0.4 0.4]. I suspect what you really want is the combination of two linear sections.

Comment: this colormap goes from blue to white.